# Convert multiple array formed inside a loop to single array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting following kind of array while i loop the contents i need to convert this array format to the following format , This below one is the actual array i am getting while i loop.

```
Array
(
    [jasmine] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => bb
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

)
Array
(
    [rose] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 0.5
            [3] => d
        )

)
Array
(
    [strawberry] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 42
            [2] => 0.5
            [3] => f
        )
)
```

And the Resultant array which i need is the below one how can i achieve this any helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Array(
    [jasmine] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => bb
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )
    [rose] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 0.5
            [3] => d
        )
    [strawberry] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 42
            [2] => 0.5
            [3] => f
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I put all the arrays in the $arrays var, for reading purposes:

```
$arrays = array(
    array(
        'jasmine' => array('a','bb','c','d')
    ),
    array(
        'rose' => array('a','4','0.5','d')
    ),
    array(
        'strawberry' => array('a','42','0.5','f')
    )
);
```

Then an array merge will do it:

```
$result = array_merge($arrays[0],$arrays[1],$arrays[2]);
```

The result will be (var_dump):

```
array(3) { ["jasmine"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(2) "bb" [2]=> string(1) "c" [3]=> string(1) "d" } ["rose"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(3) "0.5" [3]=> string(1) "d" } ["strawberry"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(2) "42" [2]=> string(3) "0.5" [3]=> string(1) "f" } }
```